# Manage Magento Store zone wise?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, zone

Here are my reuirements that i want in the extension to be build. I am a PHP Developer & wants to create a Magento Extension that can:

Create Zones based on selected countries?
Set my store different (in terms of products , promotions, slider , offers , dsicounts new arrivals whole website) based on zones created!
I will use MaxMind IP Address Location and then redirect the user to the store and whole store will be shown according to that Customers Zone.
Further more i want to set a Categories , inventory , shipping based on zones?
Now what i have explored is that i am able to find extensions naming : Zone Pricing, Zone Manager, and Advanced Pricing http://innoexts.com/promotions/pricing/ but it costs too much i can't bare the cost of these plugins.

further more i believe that these extensions will not suit my requirements.

I need suggestions that what if i create my own extension like the way i want but creating a extension have a lot of questions in my mind.

Help needed!!!

Comment: Create a store view per zone which has default currencies, language and categories etc. Use Maxmind to for Geo IP lookup and then switch to appropriate store view. Set a cookie to say you've done the check so you don't do Geo IP lookup on every page request, it will kill your site. I know I have built a module that does what you are attempting too!

Comment: Please can you guide me more in order to achieve this goal ? I will use MaxMind i have its Paid api but how do my customer will create zones? lets say i create a extension but how do i manage my store based on that store?

Comment: You said "Create a store view per zone which has default currencies, language and categories etc" How can i do that ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work

In admin, System->Manage Stores